# Lattice structure of free abelian group on a set $X$

Tags: group-theory, lattice-orders, free-abelian-group

Let $X$ be a set and denote $\mathbb{Z}^{(X)}$ for the free abelian group on $X$. That is, $\mathbb{Z}^{(X)}$ consists of all the finite sums $\sum_{x \in X}n_xx$, with coefficients $n_x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Similarly, denote free commutative monoid on $X$ by $\mathbb{N}^{(X)}$ (so $\mathbb{N}^{(X)}$ consists of all the finite sums $\sum_{x \in X}n_xx$, with $n_x \in \mathbb{N}$). One can define a left and right invariant partial order on $\mathbb{Z}^{(X)}$ as follows:

$$a \leq b \Leftrightarrow b-a \in \mathbb{N}^{(X)},$$

for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^{(X)}$. How does one obtain a lattice structure on $\mathbb{Z}^{(X)}$?

Comment: Just use the lattice structure on $\mathbb{Z}$ itself.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is totally ordered, but $\mathbb{Z}^{(X)}$ isn't. So how would this work?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is totally ordered, but $\mathbb{Z}^{(X)}$ isn't. So how would this work?

Comment: The lattice structure is obtained by letting $(a_x)\wedge(b_x) = (a_x\wedge b_x)$ and $(a_x)\vee(b_x) = (a_x\vee b_x)$. Since almost all coordinates are equal to $0$, the resulting element also lies in the appropriate structure.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @J.Bosser I think Arturo gave enough details. What have you tried?

Comment: @YCor I am confused by his notation

Comment: He denotes $(a_x)$ the family $(a_x)_{x\in X}$, that is, the function $X\to\mathbb{Z}$, $x\mapsto a_x$.

Comment: Oh okay, so this simply corresponds to the sum $\sum_{x \in X}a_xx$

Comment: Yes but his notation is more flexible (it can be used for an arbitrary direct sum of abelian groups).